# can sessions take part in the include function?

Tags: php, if-statement, session, header, include

I got 3 files: index.php / header.php and footer.php

I want the session go ahead of header.php

index.php

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
// Some Data inside index.php
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

header.php

```
<?php if(session('access_token')) { ?>
```

footer.php

```
<?php } ?>
```

how can I make this method gonna work?
I need the session start on header.php but dont wanna close him there!

Comment: Do you start your sessions on every page that you use sessions on? `<?php session_start(); ?>`. Needs to be the first thing on the page.

Comment: You are confusing terms here, what you are talking about is not _starting_ the session, but wrapping a certain block of output into an if condition that checks a particular value _in_ the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set PHP Session's in any file, as long as you always have them started, so ensure that you include `header.php` in all of your files that you want to protect.

Your header.php should include:

```
<?php

//Start PHP session if not already started
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}

?>
```

Your index,php file could include something like this:

```
<?php

/* Include header */
require("header.php");

if(isset($_SESSION["access_token"])){
   /* Content only if the access token is in session */
} else {
   die("Access token not found");
}

/* Include footer */
include("footer.php");

?>
```

As for your footer.php, this shouldn't affect any of the above PHP code or alter the outcome of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

I think You cannot do that beetween another php file. but i have solution
first
make php file to include all your header, index, and footer

then you can make like this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
  include("header.php"); 
  include("index.php");
  include("footer.php");
} else {
   die; // or you can use header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); 
}
```

Comment: session is not a function defined by PHP, I think OP meant to use `$_SESSION`

Comment: im sorry i forget i dont use CI i mean isset($_SESSION['access_token'])

Comment: but in the main purpose i mean is to look at MVC concept that include all of the file in init.php